# empty?: unbound identifier

Tags: racket, identifier, unbound

ORIGINAL QUESTION: Write a recursive Racket function "more" that takes two lists, xs and ys, as parameters and returns true if xs has more elements than ys and false otherwise. For example (more '(1 2 3) '(1 2)) should evaluate to true while (more '(1 2 3) '(0 1 2)) should evaluate to false.

```
(define (more xs ys)
        (if (empty? ys)
                (if (empty? xs) #false #true)
        (if (empty? xs) #false (more (cdr xs) (cdr ys)))))
        

(writeln (more '(1 2 3) '(1 2)))
(writeln (more '(1 2 3) '(0 1 2 3)))
(writeln (more '(1 2 3) '(0 1 2)))
```

I get an error of ":13: empty?: unbound identifier in: empty?"
How is 'empty?' an unbound identifier.

Comment: Or, you can use `null?`, which is part of the standard, instead of `empty?`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using `#lang racket/base` (has `#lang racket/base` in the first line). In `#lang racket/base`, `empty?` is not provided to you by default.

Your assignment probably expects you to use a student language (click the bottom left dropdown button in DrRacket to change to, say, Beginning Student), and `empty?` will be provided to you be default.

Alternatively, if you really mean to use `#lang racket/base`, you can add `(require racket/list)` to make `empty?` available to you.

Alternatively, change `#lang racket/base` to `#lang racket` which will automatically `(require racket/list)` along with several other libraries.